# HTTP to HTTPS (SSL) without redirect (Twitter Example)

Tags: ssl, twitter, https, security, hsts

I am trying to optimize my site for all HTTPS.  I know that Twitter is all HTTPS and I noticed that they don't redirect HTTP to HTTPS, but instead just initiate an HTTPS connection.

Here is a screenshot of Google Chrome's Network Activity, notice there is no redirect (301/302), the HTTP request (first line) just hangs as pending and the second line is the HTTPS page.  Note, I have cleared all my browser cache so HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) shouldn't matter.

[image: Twitter Network Activity]

Here is another screenshot of the request/response for the HTTPS page.  Notice, that it seems Twitter inserts some fields into the REQUEST, such as :scheme

[image: Twitter HTTPS Headers]

How do they do this?  I would assume its faster so that if a user types twitter.com into their browser, instead of a redirect (think extra network round trip), Twitter seems to seamlessly move to SSL (HTTPS).

A follow on question would be, does this work in all browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have been added to a list of [preloaded](http://www.chromium.org/sts) HSTS sites in Chrome and Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: You should add more to this answer than just a link, such as the header.

Comment: The author of the question clearly knows what HSTS is. Sometimes an answer is just an answer.  :)